# Gostaria que um usuário cadastrasse um limite único de markers no mapa

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

Bom dia pessoal, gostaria de saber, se tem como eu determinar um limite máximo de cadastros de markers há um usuário, dependendo do seu nível de acesso no banco de dados. Exemplo:

CREATE TABLE `tb_users` (

`id_users` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`senha` varchar(15) NOT NULL,

`nome` varchar(35) NOT NULL,

`telefone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,

`status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`pagseguro` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id_users`)

)

Na tabela acima, caso o usuário estivesse com nível 2 de acesso na coluna **pagseguro**, ele poderia então cadastrar 4 markers no mapa.
Enfim, quero saber como eu coloco esse limite ao usuário??

Comment: Essa regra tem de ser tratada na aplicação e não no banco.

Answer (score 0):

A princípio como seria um limite único de marcadores. a relação seria 1 para 1 para uma outra tabela com referencia a pague seguro; única dependência q notei para a indicação da quantidade, normalizando.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

contudo, observe que é um varchar como chave primária; eu recomendaria uma outra tabla pague seguro, contendo id_pagseguro, um campo com descrição, e a quantidade de marcadores ...; Dessa forma referenciaria um integer[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].